# Render a d3 pie chart in angular with angular-nvd3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

https://plnkr.co/edit/vE5Km2?p=preview

I want to render an d3 pie chart in angular with [angular-nvd3](https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/blob/master/README.md). I have no errors and all of the associated scripts are loading.

I'm not sure how to call the function inside of the directive-- 
The supplied directive is:

```
<nvd3 options='options' data='data'></nvd3>
```

which I changed to:

```
<nvd3 options='vm.options' data='vm.data'></nvd3>
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div ng-controller='MainController'>
    <nvd3 options='vm.options' data='vm.data'></nvd3>
  </div>
```

**main.controller:**

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('blah').controller('MainController', MainController);

    function MainController () {
        var vm = this;

        vm.initSampleData = initSampleData; // set up the var

        function initSampleData() {
            vm.options = {
                'chart': {
                    'type': 'pieChart',
                    'height': 500,
                    'showLabels': true,
                    'duration': 500,
                    'labelThreshold': 0.01,
                    'labelSunbeamLayout': true,
                    'legend': {
                        'margin': {
                            'top': 5,
                            'right': 35,
                            'bottom': 5,
                            'left': 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            vm.data = [
                {key: 'One', y: 5},
                {key: 'Two', y: 2},
                {key: 'Three', y: 9},
                {key: 'Four', y: 7},
                {key: 'Five', y: 4},
                {key: 'Six', y: 3},
                {key: 'Seven', y: .5}
            ];
        }
    }

})(window.angular);
```

Route (not using directive, getting ready for angular 2.0) if i add
    MainRoute.$inject = ['$routeProvider', 'nvd3'];  it errors...

```
function MainRoute($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            controller: 'MainController as vm',
            templateUrl : 'main.html',
            bindToController: false
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to make an alias to your controller, and it will solve your problem.

```
<div ng-controller='MainController as vm'>
```

You assigned `data` to controllers object, but in view, before you will give your controller alias it could be called by its own name, so before you add alias it was `MainController.data`, after you add it like I mentioned before it will be - `vm.data`.

Hope it will help you

**EDITED**

Here is [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vNcsv5FEqO4Lx6tSuXe0?p=preview) with working code. Your problems was:

- You did not init angular module with `ng-app="yourModule"`
- You inserted routing but did not use `<ui-view>` to make them know where it should be used

Comment: @cdb, could you provide plunker? it will be much easier to play around with it

Comment: @cdb, example is broken, check out console.

Comment: Hi Mikki, okay, fixed those library errors, thanks for letting me know. No errors now.. but still, no pie chart either ;)

Comment: @cdb, Updating my answer

Comment: Thank you so much Mikki for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @cdb, have fun with angular :)